# How to get the IP address and a computer's current session's name?

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to get the computer's current session's name and its IP address on which a C++ application runs ?

Will I need to use the.NET framework? If so, how ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes it's possible within running OS's that are aware of IP stack, and the currently assigned IP-address. No, you don't need to use .NET framework to do this in [tag:c++].

Answer (score 3):

Neither the C++ language and it's library provide such information today (2014).
You have to either use the API provided by the OS (certainly in C), or use a library that abstract that so that you don't have to have different code for different OS.

The .Net framework have nothing to do directly with C++ so no you are not forced to use it. It's one possibility among others. For example, Qt, Poco, RakNet, Enet and Boost( with Boost.Asio) are different libraries providing networking libraries which might provide what you are looking for.